# How to show a sideTab on total screen in Mobile View?

Tags: html, css, styles

I have a problem with my sideTab.

When I click on an icon the tab appears on the right of the screen.

So, when the screen goes to mobile sizes I would like to see the sideTab on all of the screen.

HTML

```
<div class="d-block sideTabResp">
    /***/
</div>
```

CSS

```
.sideTabResp {
    height:100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: calc(-100vw);
    width: calc(30vw);
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
    transition: right ease 0.5s;
    padding-top: 25px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

I tried something like @mediaquery but I wasn't able to do it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome on SO.

You know the answer to your question, you just need to get more information. Go check [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp), and go learn how [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/overview/) used to manage grid and mediaqueries

Try to add this into your stylesheet

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .sideTabResp {
        width: 100%;
        right: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
}
```